# "case" operator for System-F natural numbers coded with RankNTypes fails to typecheck

Tags: haskell, types, polymorphism, rank-n-types, impredicativetypes

In Haskell, if one enables the `RankNTypes` extension

```
{-# Language RankNTypes           #-}
```

then one can define the natural numbers as they are encoded in System-F:

```
type Nat = forall a. a -> ((a -> a) -> a)

zero :: Nat 
zero = \z s -> z 

succ :: Nat -> Nat
succ n = \z s -> s (n z s)

fold :: a -> (a -> a) -> Nat -> a
fold z s n = n z s
```

Yay!  The next step is to define the *case* operation: the idea is that

```
caseN :: Nat -> a -> (Nat -> a) -> a 
caseN n z f = "case n of 
    zero -> z 
    succ m -> f m"
```

Of course that's not directly possible.  One thing that is possible is to define the natural numbers as normally `{data Nats = Zero | Succ Nats}` and define "conversions" between `Nat` and `Nats`, and then use the syntactic `case` construct built-in to Haskell.

In the untyped lambda calculus, `caseN` can be written as

```
caseN n b f = snd (fold (zero, b) (\(n0, _) -> (succ n0, f n0)) n)
```

following a trick apparently discovered by Kleene for defining the predecessor function.  This version of `caseN` does look like it should typecheck with the type given above.  `(zero, b) :: (Nat, b)` and `\(n0, _) -> (succ n0, f n0) :: (Nat, b) -> (Nat, b)`, so `fold (zero, b) (\(n0, _) -> (succ n0, f n0)) n :: (Nat, b)`.

However this doesn't typecheck in Haskell.  Trying to isolate the inner function `\(n0, _) -> (succ n0, f n0)` with

```
succf :: (Nat -> b) -> (Nat, b) -> (Nat, b)
succf f (n, _y) = (succ n, f n)
```

reveals that the `ImpredicativeTypes` extension may be needed, as `succf` seems to require that extension.  For the more typical `{data Nats = Zero | Succ Nats}`, the `caseN` construct does work (after changing to the appropriate `fold`, and `Zero`, `Succ`).

Is it possible to get `caseN` to work on `Nat` directly?  Is a different trick needed?

Comment: I was going to suggest Mogensen–Scott encoding, but I think you will hit the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

I think the typical trick is to use a data type (or `newtype`, as pointed out by a commenter) wrapper.  To start, instead of defining `Nat` as a type synonym, you can define it as:

```hs
newtype Nat = Nat { unNat :: forall a. a -> ((a -> a) -> a) }
```

This is isomorphic to your definition, except that you must explicitly wrap and unwrap the contents.

We can continue by writing the same definitions you had:

```hs
zero :: Nat
zero = Nat $ \z s -> z
succ :: Nat -> Nat
succ (Nat n) = Nat $ \z s -> s (n z s)
fold :: a -> (a -> a) -> Nat -> a
fold z s (Nat n) = n z s
```

This is basically what you already had, but now with explicit wrapping and unwrapping using `Nat` (as both constructor and pattern).

At this point, your final definitions just work:

```hs
caseN :: Nat -> b -> (Nat -> b) -> b
caseN n b f = snd (fold (zero,b) (\(n0,_) ->  (succ n0,f n0)) n)

succf :: (Nat -> b) -> (Nat, b) -> (Nat, b)
succf f (n,_y) = (succ n, f n)
```

Comment: I'd note that the wrapper could as well be a `newtype`. A `data` would be needed for an _existential_, but this is a universal.

Comment: Yup, `RankNTypes` allows *implicit* impredicative polymorphism under `(->)`, and a good intuition for this “trick” is that the `newtype` allows impredicativity *explicitly* under other constructors: the constructor `Nat` allows abstraction (forall introduction); the deconstructor `unNat`, instantiation (elimination).